# Get a JSON Key based off of a user select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, key, each

I am currently creating a tool that allows users to put in their state and category to see what the 3 price plans are. These 2 selections (state/category) will be picked via select field, and the data containing these numbers is in a JSON file:

```
[{ 
    "Alabama/Category1/Price1":"$123,123 ",
    "Alabama/Category1/Price2":"$123,123 ",
    "Alabama/Category1/Price3":"$123,123 ",
    "Alabama/Category2/Price1":"$345,345 ",
    "Alabama/Category2/Price2":"$345,345 ",
    "Alabama/Category2/Price3":"$345,345 ",
    "Alabama/Category3/Price1":"$456,789 ",
    "Alabama/Category3/Price2":"$456,789 ",
    "Alabama/Category3/Price3":"$456,789 ",
    "Alabama/Category4/Price1":"$321,321 ",
    "Alabama/Category4/Price2":"$321,321 ",
    "Alabama/Category4/Price3":"$321,321 ",
    "Alaska/Category1/Price1":"$123,123 ",
    "Alaska/Category1/Price2":"$123,123 ",
    "Alaska/Category1/Price3":"$123,123 ",
    "Alaska/Category2/Price1":"$345,345 ",
    "Alaska/Category2/Price2":"$345,345 ",
    "Alaska/Category2/Price3":"$345,345 ",
    "Alaska/Category3/Price1":"$456,789 ",
    "Alaska/Category3/Price2":"$456,789 ",
    "Alaska/Category3/Price3":"$456,789 ",
    "Alaska/Category4/Price1":"$321,321 ",
    "Alaska/Category4/Price2":"$321,321 ",
    "Alaska/Category4/Price3":"$321,321 ",
}]
```

Basically on button click, I would like to loop through the JSON file and get the State/Category based off the users selections. Being that there are some "/"'s in that key path, I tried stashing the users selection in a variable, so that I could target each price point and display them on the page. My way of trying that was stashing it in a variable like so:

```
var test = stateSelected + '/' + categorySelected + '/Price1';
```

This, however does not work, and was wondering if there was any additional insight as to how to achieve this? Reading some other material, it seems some are recommending to use $.parseJSON, but that was not working either. For that I used:

```
$.getJSON("json_data.json", function(obj) {
            $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key, value) {

                //code here
            });
        });
```

Sorry for the longevity on this, but too many times on this site I have seen people not give enough information for people to be able to understand the real issue, and I hope I have outlined mine correctly. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Also, if you think there is a different way to present the JSON data other than the way I have it here, let me know. The data will be updated via spreadsheet and I used an Excel -> JSON translator tool and this was the way it spit back out the data.

Comment: What is `data` in `$.parseJSON(data)`? Why doesn't your code use `obj`?

Comment: Your JSON file contains an array of objects. Why is it in an array? What if the same `State/Category/Price` is in multiple items in the array?

Comment: Doesn't `obj[0][test]` return what you want?

Comment: You are correct, it should be (obj). In Re: "What if the same State/Category/Price is in multiple items in the array?", I believe that is what @Tudor mentioned in his answer. I have put another question out there to try and get the JSON formatted differently, but the only issue was that I kind of at the disposal of the Excel -> JSON tool and thats the only data tht was spit back to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd format the JSON in the following way:

```
var options = {
   Alabama: {
     Category1: {
       Price1: "$123, 123",
       Price2: "$123, 123",
     }
   }
}
```

and then:

```
var priceOptions = options[stateSelected][categorySelected];
```

Comment: I agree this would be the easiest way to access the JSON. The only issue here is that the way the tool (https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) exports the Excel data that I am getting is the way I posted it above. If you know of a tool that exports spreadsheet data in the way you have mentioned, I'd love for you to share! Lastly, the data is being put together now, so I can ask whoever is inputting the data to the spreadsheet to put it in any form I ask them too. Thanks again!

Comment: You can create another question in which to ask how to transform the excel file to this form of JSON and post a sample of the excel file and mention mr-data-converter.

Comment: the JSON format you put above comes up invalid in JSON validators. You don't think theres any way of using my original JSON format? Even if it is a long workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you **cannot** alter the JSON then you'll have to iterate through each key in the object:

```
function getPricePoints(state, category, onComplete)
{
    $.getJSON("json_data.json", function(obj)
    {
        var result = {};
        for(key in obj)
        {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.indexOf(state + "/" + category + "/") == 0)
            {
                result[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }

        onComplete(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you **can** alter the way the JSON is represented then why not store the data like so:

```
var options = {
    "Alabama/Category1" : {
        "Price1":"$123,123 ",
        "Price2":"$123,123 ",
        "Price3":"$123,123 "
    },
    "Alabama/Category2" : {
        "/Price1":"$345,345 ",
        "Price2":"$345,345 ",
        "Price3":"$345,345 "
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you get slash the user's inputs and get all the prices options for that combination of state and category?

```
test = stateSelected + '/' + categorySelected;
var priceOptions = options[test];
```